# Fitting a regression

Tags: regression

I really need help with fitting a good regression model.
All the graphs: Linear, quadratic and residual:
http://pho.to/7WPL6
I am not sure whether to go with a linear graph or quadratic.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use AIC to see whether additional model complexity (the quadratic term) is justified. Based on you figure, it is unlikely.

Comment: I am only a high school student and I am not even sure what AIC is, I have a slight idea in reading residual plots, i am just hoping for some opinions from u guys about what i should use?

Comment: Akaike information criterion, which penalizes for additional model complexity. This is a little bit of an over-simplification, but looking at your quadratic model it is quite similar to the linear one (so the quadratic term must not be contributing a lot), so I would use that as an indication to choose linear over quadratic.